# Word's meaning in a particular (provided) context?

Tags: speech, listening

What does a girl say at 0:14 in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i31s8F0fkCw  ?

1.He's got extra ???? Bits? Pits? Either one, what does it mean? If I'm not mistaken bits can be a reference to human genitals. If that's the case here, what does it mean? He's got both male's and female's ones?

2.What's the guy's last (and overall last) phrase in that video?

Thanks!
Anthony.

Comment: She says ***It's** got extra **bits*** (or feasibly ***He's** got...* - it's so "unstressed" I can't be sure). And you're quite right - it probably *is* a reference to "extra bits" in the genital area. But we've got no clue as to *what* those extra bits actually are (that's pure speculation). At the end, he snorts (slightly suppressed laugh) and says ***I'm sorry!***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The woman is feeling incompetent.  She knows the baby needs cleaning and changing (because he pooped), but she's saying she doesn't know the right way of doing it.  When she says, "He's got extra bits," she means that the baby, being male, has a penis and testicles, and she's squeamish (uncomfortable) and unsure of how to go about it.

We know what needs cleaning is poop because the man subsequently says, "It's a little poop, nothing more."

The woman explains that there are no diapers in the house.  The implication is that this is her fault.  I infer that she has primary custody and has asked the man (who is the baby's father, and who doesn't live with her) to come over and help her figure out how to do basic care of a baby boy.

I think what happens at the end is that the man snorts and says, "I swear," under his breath.

(The baby's male anatomy is perfectly normal.  The woman's squeamishness is probably a plot device.)

Answer (score 0):

She is saying, 'He's got extra bits.' She means she is unfamiliar with her (male) child's anatomy...

His closing line is, 'I'm sorry.' He's apologising for laughing at her.

Comment: Thank you! And by using the word 'extra' she implies that she doesn't have those? (they are extra within her (female) anatomy?)

Comment: Yes, that's what she's saying.

Comment: @Danilov: As I said in my first comment, *precisely* what "bits" she's referring to is entirely a matter of idle speculation. It's possible, for example, that she's only every been "intimately acquainted" with Jewish males, and that she's referring to the foreskin (not recognizing it, she may be unsure whether that's ***a** bit* or plural ***bits***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you! I got you. The guy then replies: "Nothing you haven't seen before." So, he probably thinks she means basic set (penis and testicles). And she gives him the kind of "Oh, you're a smart ass" glance thus likely agreeing with him. What do you think?

Comment: @Danilov: As I'm now saying for the *third* time, I think we're seriously into the realms of idle speculation - regarding a *situation* where we (or at least ***I***) don't really have sufficient context to fully understand every possible nuance. For example, it's at least *possible* she's referring to a picture of her own child - but even that doesn't prove she's ever seen a male penis (pre- or post-pubescent, erect or flaccid). Perhaps she's one of those people who only ever make love in the dark, or with their eyes closed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers looks like I have to try and give it the most all-embracing  interpritation (in another language) not to distort the meaning. Thanks again!

Comment: @Danilov: The only aspect of this issue that really involves *use of **English*** (as opposed to matters of social interaction, prior history of conversants, etc.) is the (contextually amplified) connotations of the word ***bits*** with genitalia. The man has [*his dangly bits*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his+dangly+bits%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and (more recently, by association, I suspect) the woman has [*her lady bits*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22her+lady+bits%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (often as the one-word form ***ladybits***).